# Java AWT KeyListener not working

Tags: java, applet, awt, keylistener, keyevent

I have been playing around with Java and I added a KeyListener. When I type a key it prints "0" and I would like it to print the key code.

Key.java

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Key implements KeyListener {
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("TYPED: " + Integer.toString(e.getKeyCode()));
}
}
```

Main.java

```
public void init() {
    addKeyListener(new Key());
    addMouseListener(new Mouse());

    this.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 255));
    this.setSize(screen);
}
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them. Is this Swing or AWT based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the doc :

```
void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
```

> Invoked when a key has been typed. See the class description for
>   KeyEvent for a definition of a key typed event.

So go through the description :

```
public int getKeyCode()
```

> Returns the integer keyCode associated with the key in this event.
>   Returns: the integer code for an actual key on the keyboard. (**For
>   KEY_TYPED events, the keyCode is VK_UNDEFINED**.)

And the constant `VK_UNDEFINED` is :

```
public static final int VK_UNDEFINED = 0;
```

So that's totally normal you only get 0.

You should use :

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("TYPED: " + e.getKeyChar());
}
```

Here's an [example](http://www.javaexamples.org/java/java.awt.event/keytyped-in-keyadapter.html) using the three methods.

Answer (score 0):

For KEY_TYPED event, the Key Code is undefined. Check the java docs:
 `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode()`

Use getKeyChar() instead.